# How can I select an input row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Okay so my goal is to make a auto generating sign templete.
I have a "Data" sheet with four columns. I then have a second "Print" sheet that has my templete. I want to be able to enter the the row number or the "name" which is the first column on the data sheet into a cell outside of the Tempelete. Then have each column in whatever row was selected auto fill into the templete. Right now I have it just manually selecting the cell for each column in the first input row. What would be the easiest way to get this outcome? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQniY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqxQe.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

place row number in `print!H1`

then use:

```
=INDIRECT("Data!A"&H1)
```